# Why does my app shut down if i use service android?

Tags: java, android, shutdown

I'm trying to make a simple audio player. When I create it in the main activity without service, it works correctly, music is playing (it works if I press power button to turn off the screen) and this is still working correctly after turn on the screen. But if I use service for playing music in the background, my app shuts down when I press power button for turn on the screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listSongs = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listSongs = getAllMusicInfo();
        intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundPlayer.class);

        Button buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startService);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(intent);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Button buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopService);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(intent);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It's stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class BackgroundPlayer extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        player = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            player.setDataSource((String) MainActivity.listSongs.get(0).get("path"));
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {}
}

06-05 09:58:54.206 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer V/MediaPlayer: start
```

06-05 09:58:54.206 31873-31885/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-05 09:58:54.206 31873-31885/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer V/MediaPlayer: Received MEDIA_STARTED
06-05 09:58:54.206 31873-31885/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer V/MediaPlayer: callback application
06-05 09:58:54.206 31873-31885/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer V/MediaPlayer: back from callback
06-05 09:58:54.236 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer I/MediaPlayer: Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
06-05 09:58:54.236 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
06-05 09:58:54.256 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: getCurrentPosition: 192 (msec)
06-05 09:58:54.256 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: isPlaying: 1
                                                                                    << 
06-05 09:59:25.526 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-05 09:59:25.526 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41660bc0)
06-05 09:59:25.526 31873-31873/com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.vitaliylevashov.serviceplayer, PID: 31873
                                                                                   android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
                                                                                       at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:64)
                                                                                       at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
                                                                                       at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5346)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:3487)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you post LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

add a service tag in Manifest ,may be you havent added that in manifest

`<service android:name=".MyService" />`

request to post error log/logcat

Comment: Hi, i'm add a service tag in Manifest but it's still not working